# Append timezone to time which is a date Object

Tags: javascript, angular, date, primeng

I am working on customizing primeng component for my requirement I came across a problem where I had to select a time and also select the time zone it should not affect the time selected but has to update the timezone as shown in the picture
[image]

I want to update only the timezone which is GMT to UTC as per selection

is there any way to update timezone without changing the date I tried finding a solution but failed please help on the problem

NOTE: I have customized the TIMEZONE selection

Comment: You can use https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: i dont want to use any external library for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone

Comment: I tried this `new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})` but this changes the date and time according to timezone i just want to append the timezone not change date or time according to time zone .

Comment: Append? Or store timezone as separate variable ?

Comment: just appent the timezone in date Object

Comment: console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone) will give you time zone

Comment: If i select the another timezone in selection that should be appeneded thats my requirement

Comment: Yes you can select timezone from your list and append it, But you might end up with an invalid date, it's better you use moment.js

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toISOString()` of basic JS date object (check for date docs) and then change it as you want.
But I recommend you to use external library (if possible with immutable instances of datetime) even if you do not prefer to. Especially when your application will be strongly dependent on resolving multiple timezones.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours)?

```js
let today = new Date(Date.now());

console.log(today.toISOString());
today.setUTCHours(10);
console.log(today.toISOString());
```

Also using `new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))` you can create a new date object from a specific UTC time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

This [article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/) can help you as well.